# Python programmatically set dynamic custom docstring for each method of the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, docstring

I am want to achieve dynamically to call a function and generate me a docstring and to be applied for the class methods i need.

**Example is below what i have and what i want to achieve, for each method i have a docstring that starts with triple quotes**

**Currently have the following**

```
class MyClass(BaseHandler, ABC):
    def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass, self).initialize(*args, **kwargs)
        self.description = 'My Class'

    @authenticated()
    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        """
        <div>Method GET</div>
        <div>Description: retrieve list My Class</div>
        """
        # some code here
        self.write({
            'success': True,
            'data': self.description
        })

    @authenticated()
    @coroutine
    def post(self):
        """
        <div>Method POST</div>
        <div>Description: update item My Class</div>
        """
        # some code here
        self.write({
            'success': True,
            'data': self.description
        })
```

**Inside of each method i have a docstring hardcoded and works fine, but i want to achieve to insert the docstring using a function.**

**Desired result**

```
def generate_docstring(name, method):
    docstring = """
       <div>Method %s</div>
       <div>Description: retrieve list %s</div>
       """ % (method, name)
    return docstring

class MyClass(BaseHandler, ABC):
    def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass, self).initialize(*args, **kwargs)
        self.description = 'My Class'

    @authenticated()
    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        # but this way does not work
        self.generate_docstring(name=self.description, staticmethod='GET')
        
        # some code here
        self.write({
            'success': True,
            'data': self.description
        })

    @authenticated()
    @coroutine
    def post(self):
        # but this way does not work
        self.generate_docstring(name=self.description, staticmethod='POST')
        
        # some code here
        self.write({
            'success': True,
            'data': self.description
        })
```

**There is any way to use a function and call under each method and generate the docstring?**

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a decorator, though I feel like there's a simpler way to do this.

```
def generate_docstring(name, method, action):
    def inner(obj):
        obj.__doc__ = """
            <div>Method {method}</div>
            <div>Description: {action} {name}</div>
            """.format(name=name, method=method, action=action)
        return obj
    return inner

class MyClass:
    description = 'My Class'

    @generate_docstring(description, 'GET', 'retrieve list')
    def get(self):
        pass

    @generate_docstring(description, 'POST', 'update item')
    def post(self):
        pass
```

Afterwards, `help(MyClass)` says:

```
class MyClass(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  get(self)
 |      <div>Method GET</div>
 |      <div>Description: retrieve list My Class</div>
 |  
 |  post(self)
 |      <div>Method POST</div>
 |      <div>Description: update item My Class</div>

...
```

Comment: let me see it it works, than it totaally satisfy me with a decorator, decorator is more clear than to do something i tried, let me see if my code will recognize the docstrings

Comment: thanks a lot, it works perfect. Just want to ask, there is a way to pass the translation tag for the string in the decorator like _('retrieve list')? as in the decorator no handler and my _ is available in the handler only. can somehow pass like this _('retrieve list') for transaltion purposes?

Comment: @ionluchian Welcome! I'm not sure what you mean about the translation though, and I don't have much experience with it myself. Maybe you should post another question?

Comment: no worries, i got the answer i needed and works perfect, regarding translation maybe in another question will post, as it is not so important.